# export excel to sql using visual basic

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

Was hoping if someone could help script this for me

I am trying to create a excel file with a macro attached to a button that will export the data to sql.
My sql table is as follows

```
    RecordedPeriod (datetime, not null)

    EventDate (varchar(8), not null)

    ID (int, not null)

    DeptCode (varchar(2), not null)

    OpCode (varchar(2), not null)

    StartTime (time(0), not null)

    FinishTime (time(0), not null)

    Units (int, not null)
```

While creating the macro in Visual Basic for Applications my code is as follows

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim iRowNo As Integer
Dim sRecordedPeriod, sEventDate, sID, sDeptCode, sOpCode, sStartTime, sFinishTime, sUnits  As String

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=db1\db1;Initial Catalog=ProdTrack;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    'Skip the header row
    iRowNo = 2

    'Loop until empty cell in FirstName
    Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
        sRecordedPeriod = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
        sEventDate = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
        sID = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
        sDeptCode = .Cells(iRowNo, 4)
        sOpCode = .Cells(iRowNo, 5)
        sStartTime = .Cells(iRowNo, 6)
        sFinishTime = .Cells(iRowNo, 7)
        sUnits = .Cells(iRowNo, 8)

        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
        conn.Execute "insert into dbo.TimeLog (RecordedPeriod, EventDate, ID, DeptCode, Opcode, StartTime, FinishTime, Units) values ('" & sRecordedPeriod & "', '" & sEventDate & "', '" & sID & "', '" & sDeptCode & "', '" & sOpCode & "', '" & sStartTime & "', '" & sFinishTime & "', '" & sUnits & "')"

        iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
    Loop

    MsgBox "Data Successfully Exported."

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
```

I receive this error message when exporting.

```
    Run-time error '2147217913 (80040e07)':

    Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

This is how my excel table looks. Im trying to change the time format still getting an error. My EventDate is a Varchar in SQL so there should be no issues there.

```
    RecordedPeriod  EventDate   ID  DeptCode    OpCode  StartTime   FinishTime  Units
    NULL           6/15/2017 45318   DS         DS      8:00:00     9:00:00     500
    NULL           6/15/2017 45318   DS         DS      9:00:00     9:15:00     500
    NULL           6/15/2017 45318   DS         DS      9:15:00     9:20:00     500
```

The data in my excel file is deleted after we export to sql, and we will drop new data in daily.

Comment: well your date is in the wrong format...

Comment: @tompreston Hi there, yea just not sure where at. Can you provide an example. I don't want to change the SQL table

Comment: Date formats yyyymmdd and yyyy-mm-dd will work.

Comment: No worries, I've dropped a list of accepted formats below, print your query before you run it and make sure it complies- good luck :)

Comment: date is actually not in the wrong format as it is a varchar(8) data type in my sql table?????????

Answer (score 0):

The date that you provide in your query is not in the correct format.  Here is a list of accepted formats, you're going to need to make sure the format you use complies with this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql

I would recommend using `Debug.Print "insert int..."` and checking the format in the immediates window (in the VBExplorer), then running the query

Answer (score 0):

Consider in your design to export to XML and create rules with XSLT (or DTD, etc.) for SQL to import. XML can be a powerful way to communicate data between formats.

add: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server

This solution is more scaleable as your database and spread sheet changes. You'll instead of creating more macros, will only have to change the XML rules.

Comment: In this particular case the DB and spreadsheet will not change. Our spreadsheet will have all rows deleted after we export to sql on a daily basis. Im just trying to have a user friendly front end to input data to our db